# Why am i infinitely getting the same tweet with the Twitter Search API?

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

My code workes perfectly for other queries, but for one query I am infinitely getting the same tweet. I can't understand what the problem is.

**API call:**

```
        query='Allergic asthma OR Nonallergic asthma OR Occupational asthma OR EIB OR Exercise-induced bronchoconstriction OR Nocturnal asthma OR Cough-variant asthma'
        new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery, count=100, since_id=since_id, lang='en',tweet_mode='extended')

        if not new_tweets:
            print("No more tweets found")
            break
        for tweet in new_tweets:
            if True:
                print(jsonpickle.encode(tweet._json, unpicklable=False))

                my_file = open('searchTweets.txt','a')
                my_file.write(jsonpickle.encode(tweet._json, unpicklable=False)+'\n')
                my_file.close()

            else:
                continue
```

**Output in file:**

https://pastebin.com/JmRCsTeE

These are the JSONs of the same Tweet.

Other queries that work:

- Breast cancer OR Prostate cancer OR Colon cancer OR Lung cancer
- Type 2 diabetes OR Type 1 diabetes OR Prediabetes OR Gestational diabetes
- IBS OR D-IBS OR C-IBS OR A-IBS OR Irritable Bowel Syndrome OR Cure

Answer (score 0):

The Standard Search API recommends using 10 keywords and operators. In my query, I was using more than 10 for each. So I tried reducing the number of keywords ( which also reduced the number of operators) and it worked!

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators